# Flutter cookbook for widget that gets its state from a REST API and refreshes automatically?

Tags: flutter

What is the basic cookbook for a flutter widget that does this?

1) Displays initial state like "loading".

2) Async gets content from a REST API.

3) Updates state when the REST API returns success.

4) Refreshes content on a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065098/how-work-with-progress-indicator-in-flutter/47075568#47075568).

Generally speaking, you will have a `StatefulWidget` that calls the API on it's `initState` and store the "future" (async action in Dart) locally.

Then use `FutureBuilder` to know weither or not the data is loading/fetched/error. And display something accordingly.

Comment: Thanks that helped me out a lot.  I have a Future that executes the http get and parses the json into a model and I set it up in initState.  Everything works great and my model updates and my widgets update.  One final question.  Once my Future completes I want to schedule it to do the whole thing again after a period of time.  Suggestion?

Comment: You can use another future that will periodically call the first one again. That future would use `Future.doWhile` and `await new Future.delayed`