# Show Circular Progress Dialog in Login Screen in Flutter, how to implement progress dialog in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, progress-bar, progressdialog

I have a login form with two textfields 'UserName', 'Password' & a button 'Login'. On tap of login button I am calling an API. I want to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` during this api call. Progress dialog should show in the centre & top of login form.
I have tried `FutureBuilder` but it hides the login form shows `CircularProgressIndicator` only. I want all content of screen to show behind the `CircularProgressIndicator`.

Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:the_don_flutter/userModel.dart';
import 'package:validate/validate.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'signup.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<Login> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return LoginFormState();
  }
}

class LoginFormState extends State<Login>{

  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _passwordValidation(String value){
    if(value.isEmpty){
      return "Field Can't be empty.";
    }else if(value.length < 6)
      return "Password must be of six characters long.";
    return null;
  }

  String _checkValidEmail(String value){
    try{
      Validate.isEmail(value);
    }catch(e){
      return "Email is not valid.";
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<User> _loginUser() async{
    var response = await http.post("https://example/public/api/login", headers: {}, body: {'username':'poras@techaheadcorp.com', 'password':'123456'})
        .catchError((error) => print("Error $error"));
    print("response of login ${response.body}");
    return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 100.0, right: 20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg_green.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.fill)),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    validator: _checkValidEmail,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "abc@example.com",
                        labelText: "User Name",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    autofocus: true,),),
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  validator: _passwordValidation,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "password",
                      labelText: "Password",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  autofocus: true,)
              ],),),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Forgot Password?", textAlign: TextAlign.start, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),),
                ],),),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: _submitForm,
                child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("LOGIN", textAlign: TextAlign.start, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40.0),),
                    Icon(Icons.chevron_right, size: 40.0, color: Colors.white,),
                  ],),), ),

            Expanded(
                child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Don't have an account?", textAlign: TextAlign.start, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),),
                      Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Signup()));},
                            child: Text("REGISTER NOW!", textAlign: TextAlign.start, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,),),
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _submitForm() {
    if(formKey.currentState.validate()){
      print("Go to Home page");
      _loginUser();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065098/how-work-with-progress-indicator-in-flutter?

Comment: How about doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550853/how-do-i-do-the-frosted-glass-effect-in-flutter)? instead of flutter image you can have circular progress indicatory

Answer (score 61):

To show a `progressdialog` on button click while `api` is fetching data on login screen.

Try this

Declare this method to show a progress dialog

```
showLoaderDialog(BuildContext context){
    AlertDialog alert=AlertDialog(
      content: new Row(
        children: [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),child:Text("Loading..." )),
        ],),
    );
    showDialog(barrierDismissible: false,
      context:context,
      builder:(BuildContext context){
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

**USAGE**

on button click when api is called, call this method like this

```
onPressed: () {
                showLoaderDialog(context);
                //api here },
```

and when response is fetched dismiss that dialog like this

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Comment: Nice and simple example!

Comment: Nice example, what if we need to immune this showDialogBox from a users back button, so that if users press back button it does not remove the showDialogBox until it completes ?

Comment: @MadhavMishra barrierDismissible: true please use this and check . thanks

Comment: For me the 'pop' part did not work until I tried `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();` Perhaps it was because I was initiating the dialog from inside a drawer?

Comment: thank yu @Quicklearner for a pretty much simple answer

Answer (score 13):

This demo (with source code) should be very close to what your trying to do

[image]

It includes triggering the form validators before and after the async call.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/modal_progress_hud

Answer (score 7):

create something like `bool _isLoading = false;`

When the sign-in button is pressed then

```
onPressed: (){
  setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
  });
}
```

Meanwhile, use Stack to insert the `CircularProgressIndicator`

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
   _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Container(), //only show CircularProgressIndicator when loading
   //your login body here
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try below code snippet for it

```
class ProgressHUD extends StatelessWidget {

  final Widget child;
  final bool inAsyncCall;
  final double opacity;
  final Color color;
  final Animation<Color> valueColor;

  ProgressHUD({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.inAsyncCall,
    this.opacity = 0.3,
    this.color = Colors.grey,
    this.valueColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>();
    widgetList.add(child);
    if (inAsyncCall) {
      final modal = new Stack(
        children: [
          new Opacity(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: color),
          ),
          new Center(
            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: valueColor,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
      widgetList.add(modal);
    }
    return Stack(
      children: widgetList,
    );
  }
}
```

Use it

```
 body: ProgressHUD(
          child: screen,
          inAsyncCall: _isLoading,
          opacity: 0.0,
        ),
```

just change the state of **_isloading** true if you want to display progress.

Comment: in IOS device progress view show same as Android. How to make it plateform specific ?

Answer (score 5):

**where ever you want call this function**

```
  progressDialogue(BuildContext context) {
  //set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    content: Container(
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    ),
  );
  showDialog(
    //prevent outside touch
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      //prevent Back button press
      return WillPopScope(onWillPop: () async => false, child: alert);
    },
  );
}
```

**For dismiss call this **

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```