# Flutter - DropDown option based on option selected in first dropdown

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to implement multiple dynamic dropdown based on the option selected in the previous option.

I have api - http://webmyls.com/sts/get_advisor_village_sanch_acharya.php

This API calling three table
1) advisor
2) Sanch
3) Village

Table - **Advisor** holding a sanch_id field. 
Table - **Village** holding a sanch_id field.

I need three drop down
1) First drop down should show the **name** field from the advisor table

Ex - Selected **name: "chidambaram"**

2) Second drop down should show the **sanch_name** based of the selection from the advisor table.

Ex. First dropdown has a value of sanch_id: "2", so the second dropdown should show - sanch_name: "Sriperumbadur II",

3) Third drop down should show the list of **village_name** list mapped to the selected sanch_name in the second dropdown(table sanch).

Ex. Based on the selection from the second drop down, third drop down should display the list of rows holding **sanch_id: "2"** from table - **village**

Please help me on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567870/flutter-is-it-possible-in-flutter-to-show-another-dropdownbutton-after-another